# Word tables to Excel

Tags: c#

I was exporting tables from word to excel ,cut found out that the multi line cells in word would be split (each one in a cell) in Excel. I've known the reason that is Excel uses different line terminator than Word .are there any workarounds using C# interop ????
thanks in advance

Comment: Do you just want to cut/paste, or do you need an automation solution?

Comment: I need an automation solution.as I've made -using C# interopes- a program to get the word tables to excel when i found n this problem.